# question about projectpixelto3dray

Tags: ros, geometry, image-geometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I have a question about the function [projectPixelTo3dRay](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/image_geometry/html/c++/classimage__geometry_1_1PinholeCameraModel.html#a1f5a3957c06a249e250e74513319f8a8), according to the API the return value is a 3d ray passing through (u,v).

But what does that mean? Why Z is 1? How I can calculate the point where it intersects the ray with the floor (Z = 0)?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43947/question-about-projectpixelto3dray/) by [Alberto Martín](https://answers.ros.org/users/3121/alberto-mart%C3%ADn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2012-09-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alberto Martín](https://answers.ros.org/users/3121/alberto-mart%C3%ADn/) on 2012-09-17**:
Thanks domhege, but how I can transform between the camera system and the system floor? you know any example?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-09-17**:
Use the tf library. Obviously someone, somewhere must compute this transformation, i.e. where is the camera relative to the floor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think those are camera coordinates, Z=0 does NOT equal floor. Z=0 should equal the origin of the pinhole camera model.

You will need to transform between the camera system and whatever system you have that defines where the floor is.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0